Blazor .NET 6 Integrity issue on publish
I am working on my self project of blazor webassembly .net 6 and I am uploading it on the plesk panel. Locally it is working fine but when I upload it on the server it always shows couple of errors. Screenshot is attached below

I did manay queries following are the solutions I already tried but didn't worked me

Deletion of obj, bin, .config folder and republish.
I saw that dotnet.timezones.blat and some more files are giving 404. but when I go physically to that location I can see the files and following are the server permissions in plesk

I also updated the web.config.


Hi Azaz, please navigate to the publish folder (wwwroot/_framework/) and check icudt_EFIGS.dat and dotnet.timezones.blat exist or not ?

If can't find it, you can try below settings in your .csproj file. It can include these 2 specific files during the deployment. <ItemGroup>   <Content Include="wwwroot\_framework\icudt_EFIGS.dat" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" />   <Content Include="wwwroot\_framework\dotnet.timezones.blat" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" /> </ItemGroup>

@JasonPan Thanks for the replying. Yes I see the Plesk panel both files are there.
